# c# How to change window focus onMouseEnter event

Tags: wpf, focus, mouse, window, click

i have a WPF application that i would like to become the current focused window whenever the mouse cursor moves over it. Currently i have a onMouseEnter event that changes the cursor when the mouse moves over it so i know the system is recognizing that, however what i actually want is for the application itself to become focused as if the used had left clicked on it - so i can then perform other ops. At the moment if i move over it the cursor changes but if another app, eg - notepad had focus, focus would return to that after.

Within the onMouseEnter handler i have tried "this.Focus()" and "this.Activate()" but neither of them achive the same result as if i had clicked on the app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Posted answer will not work for WPF.  Sorry.

Try looking at this instead for WPF: http://blogs.msdn.com/nickkramer/archive/2006/03/18/554235.aspx

Comment: thanks Auxon, do you have any examples on how i would do this? and where is this done, in the event handler?

Comment: There is the SO question I just added via edit, and maybe http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/39039.  I tried finding something closer to your issue, but haven't found anything yet.  Still looking.

Comment: Sorry Grant, you need to do something different with WPF.  It sounds possible though.  Your WPF application will start receiving messages whenever the mouse moves over it.  To find out exactly which messages are fired, you can use Spy++ in the Visual Studio tool set.  I think the message you want to intercept is WM_HOVER.  If you use the sample in the link above, and just intercert WM_HOVER instead, and try to activate the form then, you may have a better result.

Comment: The message is WM_MOUSEHOVER = 0x02A1

Comment: Sorry, normally I would try out stuff before posting, but I am downloading and installing VS 2010 Beta 1.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

WPF C# Example with a MouseEnter event attached to a Grid control. If another application window has the focus it will remove it and attach the focus to the main window as if the user had left clicked on it.

```
    private void GrdContent_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF just add this line to the MainWindow constructor to get the expected result.

```
MouseEnter += (s, e) => Activate();
```

This original one line answer will only work if you don't interact with any other window.  The following will work even in that case but you will need the Nuget package "AutoItX.Dotnet".

```
private IntPtr myHandle;
public MainWindow() {
  myHandle =  new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
  MouseEnter += (s, e) => {
    Activate();
    if (AutoIt.AutoItX.WinActive(myHandle) == 0)
      AutoIt.AutoItX.WinActivate(myHandle);
    };
```